# hook_form_alter is not fired off on page refresh

Tags: drupal-7

I have made a Drupal7 module and I'm trying to load the values in hook_form_alter.
Upon save it works, but when I refresh the page it blanks out.
To show you the problem, I print the time in hook_form_alter and it does not update.
Any ideas why it is not showing the new timestamp when I refresh the page?

```
<?php

function bank_info_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['bank-info'] = [
      'title' => 'My Banking Info',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('bank_info_form'),
      'access callback' => 'bank_info_check_role',
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  ];

  return $items;
}

function bank_info_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['bank_account_number'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Bank Account Number'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#maxlength' => 20,
  );

  return $form;
}

function bank_info_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
  if(array_key_exists('bank_account_number', $form_state['values'])){
    $obj->bank_account_number = $form_state['values']['bank_account_number'];
  }
  $obj->save();
  drupal_set_message('Saved banking information successfully.');
}


function bank_info_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form['#id'] == 'bank-info-form') {
    echo date("h:i:sa");
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try to add $form_state['rebuild'] = true; ? , why do you need to fire alter each time ? maybe there another why to achieve that you want ?

Comment: @Fky that worked! Wonderful. I'm new to Drupal. What I'm trying to do is to make a form that displays and views the current values.

Comment: Great i'm glad to see that ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code has one disadvantage. It's using $form['#id'] in the 'if' clause. $form['#id'] is normally using for form 'id' attribute and may vary in some cases. Use $form_id variable instead.

```
if ($form_id == 'bank_info_form') {
  echo date("h:i:sa");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that but the problem I'm having is that the page is getting cached. I need to either delete the cache for this form or turn caching off for this specific form which I do not know how to do.

Comment: Well. Form itself isn't retrieving from cache on page refresh. Form cache fire on form submit. So it's more likely that cause is in the page cache. To disable page caching you can call `drupal_page_is_cacheable(false)` in your code. But, as far as I see, this form works only for logged in users, so normal drupal page cache shouldn't fire too. May be the source of the problem is in the browser or proxy server cache (need check wich cache headers sends your webserver) or some web server caching mechanism. Or some module which cache pages for logged in users.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. drupal_page_is_cacheable did not fix it. Note that when I add a random parameter at the end of the url in the browser, it shows the real new data.